# Populate H3 Tags with ALT Text in Sibling --> Child IMG Tags

Tags: jquery

Thanks to other helpful people, I have learned how to populate the IMG ALT attributes of images in a jQuery Accordion. Now I want to do the opposite: Take the ALT text out of a set of images and populate the parent H3 tags. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3></h3>
    <div>
        <img src="some_place.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Some stuff here">
    </div>
    <h3></h3>
    <div>
        <img src="some_place.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Some other stuff here">
    </div>
    ...(repeat several times)
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    $("h3").each(function() {
        var $title = $(this).siblings().children("img").attr("alt");
        $("h3").text($title)
        });
});
```

This works, but only by populating all H3 tags with the ALT tag from the first image. I.e., all H3 tags had the text "Some stuff here".

What am I doing wrong? Should I somehow put all the ALT text into an array, and then feed it back? Every attempt I made at that just broke the page (no array, no accordion.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` instead of `h3` inside each. `this` referes to current element

Use

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    var $title = $(this).siblings().children("img").attr("alt");
    $(this).text($title); //Use this here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
$("h3").text( function() {
    return $(this).next().children("img").attr("alt");
});
```

**[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/oyk9qnf8/)**